# Proving a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define $$\phi:\mathbb R[x,y]\rightarrow \mathbb R[x]$$ by setting $$\phi(P(x,y))=P(x,4)$$
Is $\phi$ a ring homomorphism?

So I got the $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ part down, but am having trouble proving $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$. How would I prove that without expanding out each term?

Answer (score 1):

$\phi(ab)$ would be the result of multiplying two polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, and then plugging in $4$ for $y$. On the other hand, $\phi(a) \phi(b)$ is the product of the two same polynomials, but you plug in $4$ for $y$ before you multiply. Should you end up with the same result either way?

---

Edit: Let $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$ be two polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Their product is another polynomial $r(x,y) := p(x,y) q(x,y)$. Then $$\phi(pq) = \phi(r) = r(x,4) = p(x,4) q(x,4) = \phi(p) \phi(q).$$

Comment: I tried a few examples and they all seem to end up with the same result

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: @icicle See my edit.